# Do I need this function in Python 2.7? Or is it unnecessary?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I see codes that look like this:

```
from Tkinter import *    
def main():
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
        root.title("GUI")
        root.mainloop()
```

But why do they write it in a function? Couldn't you do the same thing by typing this

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
root.wm_iconbitmap(r'c:/Python33/DLLs/txteditor.ico')
app = txtEditor(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Not sure if this is considered a "good" question if not I understand I will remove it. But I am somewhat new to Python and just see this a lot but do not understand why? Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: General function defination: Define a function iff when you see some part of your code is getting repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main purpose of wrapping codes in a predefined function name (`main` in your case) is that, when your file gets imported by its parent script thus defined function is used as the entry point.

As said by `Ethan Furman`, the code wrapped in a function can be called only when needed where as the code scattered outside a function (your second example) gets executed right after it is imported.

Besides, your first snippet is much cleaner and self explanatory than the second one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But what do you mean when your file gets imported by its parent script? Sorry for the beginner questions but I was just wondering

Comment: Suppose your above code is in `tinker_app.py`, looking at the name of the entry point function (`main`) it is first imported by other script, suppose `tinker_loader.py`. In this case `tinker_loader.py` is parent script or better even if called main script.

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do, little different from your scenario but should satisfy your curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally it is useful to import a script so that you can test, or even use, some of the functions that are in it.  If your main functionality is in a function this is easy to do.

However, if simply importing the script also executes the main functions -- well, that's not very useful.